# Flask search based on a keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i'm new with flask and i'm working on a blog project , i'm trying add a search box where a visitor or an user enter a key word , and posts related to this keyword will be displayed.
i tried the whoosh indexing but it didn't work since i'm using python3.9 so i tried this one :

```
@app.route('/search', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def search():
    search_keyword = request.form.get("search_box")
    results =  db.engine.execute("SELECT * FROM post "
                           "WHERE title = search_box ")
    return render_template('home.html', results=results)
```

trying to get the value of the input field

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" method="GET" action="search"  name="search_box">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
```

no errors but it's not working , can anyone help me please ? thanks

Comment: Do you have any entry in db which has title equal to search_box?

Comment: i'm trying to get the search_box input field value and make a search request based on it , search_box is the name of the  input field, i didn't know how to get the value of the input  in the sql request

Comment: which type of database you are using sqlite or mysql. if you are using mysql then I can give you the search command but I think it doesn't work in sqlite

Comment: i'm using sqlite database

Comment: sorry, the command doesn't work with sqlite but i have another library which is working with python 3 see here https://github.com/honmaple/flask-msearch , whoosh does not support python 3

Comment: i tried flask msearch , but it didn't work as well .. thank you anyway

Comment: Why have you got `method="GET"` and `action="search"` attributes on the input element, these should be attributes of the form element, or is this a typo?

Comment: last update :`@app.route('/search', methods =["GET"])
def search():
    if request.method == "GET":
     search_keyword = request.POST.get('search_keyword')
     results = Post.query.filter_by(title = '{{search_keyword}}').all()
     return render_template('home.html', results=results)` still doesn't work , all i got is (http://127.0.0.1:5000/?search_keyword=flask) on the top when i search for 'flask' as a keyword in the search  input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually , i ended up using  **flask_msearch**

i installed it : `pip install flask-msearch`

****init**.py** :

```
from flask_msearch import Search
...
search = Search(app)
search.init_app(app)
search.create_index(update=True)
MSEARCH_INDEX_NAME =  os.path.join(app.root_path,'msearch')
MSEARCH_PRIMARY_KEY = 'id'
MSEARCH_ENABLE = True
```

in  **models.py** :

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['title', 'content']
```

**routes.py** :

```
@app.route('/search/')
def search():
    keyword = request.args.get('query')
    posts = Post.query.msearch(keyword,fields=['title', 'content'])
    return render_template("home.html",title='Searching..' + keyword, posts=posts)
```

in my **template** :

```
<form method="GET" action="/search/">
                      <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bold">
                              
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  </div>
```

Thank you for everyone who tried to help me